# Maximum data limit of SenchaJS Ext.data.store

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm working on Sencha Touch and making an app specifically for iOS. I want to know the maximum available storage of store. Where exactly data is stored? Is it local storage of browser or your local physical storage ?

Comment: ExtJS stores generally are in memory (RAM).